# Get path from Content Uri within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have used the following methods to get the path from a Content Uri within my Activity and it works well;

```
// region Helpers

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    Log.d(TAG, "getPath: (context) " + context);

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

// end region Helpers
```

getPath is called with "this" context and the Uri

```
String filePath = getPath(this, returnUri);
```

Now, I have a Fragment that I need to get a path to get a filename to display but I can't get "getPath" to return anything but null.  I understand that the Context of a Fragment references the Activity it is attached to, so the Context always references MyActivity, regardless where it is called from (MyActivity or MyFragment).

I simply don't understand how to get around this.  I've tried adding the above code to my Fragment code as helpers, but it returns null. I've tried adding the above code back to MyActivity and call it with MyActivity.getPath and it returns null.  I've tried calling it with every variation of getContext(), getApplication(), getApplicationContext() and anything else I could throw at it.  I've Googled and read for hours and tried countless "resolutions" and am just frustrating myself.

I've also tried to think about how I can have MyActivity pass the data to the Fragment, but I'm in the onActivityResult of MyFragment, so I'm not even sure that's possible at that point.

I can normally Google and find solutions to 99% of my problems in a few minutes, but this one really has my stumped.  If I can provide anything further, please ask.

Thanks!

**UPDATE (07/09/2018)**

It seems that I inadvertently switched devices while testing this code, so the original code that did work, still works, sorta.  It works with my Samsung S7 (phone) running Android 7.0, API 24, but it doesn't work with my Samsung Tablet running Android 5.0.2 API 21. (The code used checks for >= KitKat, API 19.)

The issue seems to be the authority provider that is being returned by these devices.  For example, the return URI's for both devices are as follows;

Samsung S7 return URI - getPath: (uri) content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1397

Samsung Tab 4 return URI - getPath: (uri) content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D2193

<strike>So, I'm going to assume the authority provider changed at some point after API 21, but, at this point, I keep Googling and can't seem to find a list of providers anywhere to confirm this.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was me being a noob and learning a lesson.

I switched devices AND from where I was downloading my test file. On the S7 it was in downloads, on the Tab 4 it was from my Google Drive. Arrrg!

The above code works on both devices if the file is local to the device. It had nothing to do with context.

In the end, my solution was simple... I actually got rid of using the above code to get the path as I really didn't need the path. I wanted other info, like mime type, file name & extension.

**SOLUTION**

Create a DocumentFile object from the returned URI.

Now you have access to the mime type, filename and the extension, like so;

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getContext(), returnUri);

String mimeType = documentFile.getType();
String filePath = YourActivityClass.getPath(mContext, returnUri);
String fileName = documentFile.getName();
String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
```